# How can I convert a series of images to a valid HTML5 video

Tags: html, html5-video

I am attempting to encode a video from an image sequence, for embedding as an HTML5 video.

If any one have a answer....

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg is a free and versatile command line tool that will convert between a number of video formats and codecs, including image sequences. Some instructions for converting from an image sequence to a video file are here:

http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f

To make it work in the majority of web browsers, you'll want two versions of the video file: one in mp4 and one in webm. The command line would look roughly like this:

```sh
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg  -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis output.webm

ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg  -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

You may also want to look into options for setting the bitrates and other options.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 supports .mp4, .webm and .ogg videos, learn more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

To convert other video formats to HTML5 supported video formats, follow the steps:
http://www.aolor.com/video-converter/user-guide.html