# How to Convert animated .gif into .webm format in Python?

Tags: python, django, gif, webm

I have a web application built on Django where images and animated Gif can be uploaded. However GIF takes long time to load. I was thinking of converting all uploaded gif into webm format and show it on the frontend using HTML5 video tag. I searched a lot for doing this in Python but could not find specific solution. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133402/ffmpeg-to-convert-gif-to-webm-with-reverse-function) solution. But I want to know is it possible to convert gif into webm while uploading in python or is there any library in python from which this conversion can be accomplished?.

Comment: How is a _gif_ (image) takes more time to load than _webm_ (video)? The problem is definitely somewhere else. Are these animated gifs or something?

Comment: Yes these are animated gif. Sorry I forgot to mention. I have edited the question. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a series of images to a valid HTML5 video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033744/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-images-to-a-valid-html5-video)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can FFmpeg be used as a library, instead of a standalone program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401764/can-ffmpeg-be-used-as-a-library-instead-of-a-standalone-program)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/):

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("mygif.gif")
clip.write_videofile("myvideo.webm")
```

You can also use any other format (mp4, ogv, etc) and add parameters like bitrate='5000k' or any other parameter supported by FFMPEG. You can also use ffmpeg directly for the conversion instead of moviepy, it will be slightly faster.

Comment: Any way to get a streamable output, as in yielding chunks of the file, instead of waiting for it to finish first?
Like this one, but with video: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147454/3423324

Comment: Asked [as a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48022490/3423324)