# Python: Convert GIF To video(mp4)

Tags: python, gif, mp4

I am trying to find some way for converting GIF to mp4 using Python or library. I didn't found any solution for it. I found a library for generating gifs from videos but not the other way round.

Can anyone please give me some information on how to do it.

Comment: did you look at ffmpy? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffmpy

Answer (score 29):

Try MoviePy:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

clip = mp.VideoFileClip("mygif.gif")
clip.write_videofile("myvideo.mp4")
```

If you don't have MoviePY installed then first install it:

```
pip install MoviePy
```

Comment: When I use it , it is giving me error : TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType

Comment: It's important to also have the library "ffmpeg" installed in the system... in Alpine linux it is `RUN  apk add ffmpeg`

Comment: This works fine. But the transparency of the gif images is lost after the mp4 is created

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this. Relatively simple way is to use `ffmpeg`. There are many python bindings. `ffmpy` is one of them. Please check [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffmpy) for the documentation. Basic example:

Installation:

```
pip install ffmpy
```

Usage:

```
>>> import ffmpy
>>> ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(
...     inputs={'input.gif': None},
...     outputs={'output.mp4': None}
... )
>>> ff.run()
```

Again, there are many other ways to do this. Please find the related references here:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40638/how-to-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-an-mp4-or-mv4-on-the-command-line
2. https://sonnguyen.ws/convert-gif-to-mp4-ubuntu/
3. [How to Convert animated .gif into .webm format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620186/how-to-convert-animated-gif-into-webm-format-in-python)

Comment: This didn't work :(

Comment: This works fine. But the transparency of the gif images is lost after the mp4 is created

Answer (score -2):

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = (VideoFileClip("VIDEO.mp4")
        .subclip((1,22.65),(1,23.2))
        .resize(0.3))
clip.write_gif("nAME_OF_gif_FILE.gif")
```

You can download Video with this command if you have Youtube-dl installed:

Comment: The OP is asking for gif -> mp4