# How to save a matplotlib.pause animation to video?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, video, export

I have an animation created with `plt.pause` as below...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(10):
    plt.scatter(0, i)
    plt.pause(0.01)

plt.show()
```

How can I save this as a video file, e.g. a **.mp4** file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I have to redefine the plotting as a function with the plotted point given by a frame `i`. `plt.pause()` can be replaced by `matplotlib.animate`. Finally, I used a package suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726502/python-convert-gif-to-videomp4) to get the conversion to `.mp4` format. You will need to install `MoviePy`:

```
pip install MoviePy
```

and then I just animate the function with `matplotlib.animate` into a `.gif` format before sending it to `MoviePy`. You'll need to figure out what directory you want this all to happen in. I'm just using the current working directory.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import os
import moviepy.editor as mp


frames=20
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
def scatter_ani(i=int):
    plt.scatter(0, i)

anim = ani.FuncAnimation(fig, scatter_ani, frames=frames, interval=50)
anim.save("test.gif")

clip = mp.VideoFileClip(path+name)
clip.write_videofile("test.mp4")
```

The `gif` is then

[image: Result]

To tweak the length of the animation, check out the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/animation_api.html) for `matplotlib.animate`. For example, if you want to clear all of the previous data-points and show only the dot moving up, then you need to clear the axes in the function, and bound the y-axis so you see the motion, i.e.

```
def scatter_ani(i=int):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_ylim(0, frames+1)
    plt.scatter(0, i)
```

to get:

[image: result]