# Make a simple animation with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to create an animation of the function f(x,t)=cos(k*x-w*t) where x would be an array # from 0 to 2*pi, k any constant, w any other constant and each frame would be a value of t different from, say, 0 to 10.

I'm starting to learn about python and the matplotlib library now, I looked in the documentation but I can't understand or I couldn't find a similar problem.

One way I thought of doing it was:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,2))

T = np.linspace(0,10,100)
K = 3.
w = 1.
x = np.linspace(0, 2\*np.pi, 100)

for t in T:
    cos = np.cos(K*x - w*t)
    ax.plot(x, cos)
    plt.pause(0.001)

plt.show()
```

but the axes are printed one after the other, and not quite what I imagined. I would like each curve of this separated in a frame and not all together.

Comment: If you are looking to create animations, maybe other libraries like manim would be better for your intentions...

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73965741/13252887) similar to what you want?

Comment: it's something similar to this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following, based heavily on [this Matplotlib animation example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html), should hopefully do what you want. I've tried to add comments to help your understanding, but please comment if there's anything you don't understand.

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# create the figure and axes objects on which to plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# generate your x-data
x = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)

# set your constants
K = 3.0
w = 1.0

# define the function that you want to plot
def plotfunc(x, t, K, w):
    return np.cos(K * x - w * t)

# define t
T = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

# plot the initial function at t=0 ("line" holds the data that was
# plotted which will be updated later in the animate function)
line, = ax.plot(x, plotfunc(x, T[0], K, w))

# define animation function
def animate(i, x=None, t=None, K=None, w=None, line=None):
    # get index in t (modded with length of t, so that it repeats)
    tidx = (i + 1) % len(t)

    # update the y-axis data in the Line2D (line) object
    line.set_ydata(plotfunc(x, t[tidx], K, w))
    return line,

# set "partial" version of the animate function that presets all
# the keyword arguments to animate (apart from i)
anifunc = partial(animate, x=x, t=T, K=K, w=w, line=line)

# make the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig,  # pass the figure object
    anifunc,  # pass the animation function
    interval=20,
    blit=True,
)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Exactly what I intended to do, thank you very much!